# How can I change search address on laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a laravel powered app where when I use the search form, it leads me to the homepage while showing the correct results. I'm trying to redirect it to the_app_url/track/ instead, while giving the same results.

Below is my /routes/web.php

```
   <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


  Route::get('/', 'FrontController@index')->name('front.index');
  Route::get('aboutus', 'FrontController@aboutus')->name('front.aboutus');
  Route::get('contactus', 'FrontController@contactus')->name('front.contactus');
  Route::get('faq', 'FrontController@faq')->name('front.faq');
  Route::post('visitor/message', 'FrontController@visitorMessage')->name('visitor.message');
  Route::post('search/currier', 'FrontController@searchCurrier')->name('search.currier');
  Route::get('/track', function () {
return view('track');});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'CacheRemover'], function() {

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'CheckLogin'], function() {

        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('admin/login');
        })->name('admin');

        Route::post('authenticate', 'LoginController@authenticate')->name('admin.authenticate');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {

        Route::post('logout', function () {
            Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
            return redirect('admin');
        });
         
        /*
         * Authorise route list
         */
        //change password route
        Route::get('changePassword', 'AdminController@changePassword')->name('changepassform');
        Route::put('changePassword', 'AdminController@updatePassword')->name('changepassssubmit');
        //profile route
        Route::get('profile', 'AdminController@profileView')->name('admin.profile');
        Route::put('profile', 'AdminController@updateProfile');
        //basic setting route list
        Route::get('basicSetting', 'GeneralSettingController@basicSetting')->name('admin.basicSetting');
        Route::put('basicSetting/{basicSetting}', 'GeneralSettingController@updateBasicSetting')->name('admin.basicSettingUpdate');
        //sms setting route list
        Route::get('smsSetting', 'GeneralSettingController@smsSetting')->name('admin.smsSetting');
        Route::put('smsSetting/{smsSetting}', 'GeneralSettingController@updateSmsSetting')->name('admin.smsSettingUpdate');
        //email setting route list
        Route::get('emailSetting', 'GeneralSettingController@emailSetting')->name('admin.emailSetting');
        Route::put('emailSetting/{emailSetting}', 'GeneralSettingController@updateEmailSetting')->name('admin.emailSettingUpdate');

        //courier unit info route list
        Route::resource('courier/unit', 'UnitController');
        //courier type info route list
        Route::resource('courier/type', 'CourierTypeController');

        //Branch Info
        Route::resource('branch', 'BranchController');

        //Branch Manager Info & staff view route 
        Route::resource('branchmanager', 'BranchManagerController');
        Route::post('branchmanager/changepassword', 'BranchManagerController@changePassword')->name('branchmanager.changepassword');
        Route::get('staff/{branch}', 'UserController@allUserList')->name('admin.branch.staff');

        //dashboard
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');

        //company income route
        Route::get('company/income', 'BranchManagerController@companyIncome')->name('admin.company.income');

        //branch wise company income route
        Route::get('branch/income/{branch}', 'BranchManagerController@branchIncome')->name('admin.branch.income');
        Route::get('branch/income/{branch}/{date}', 'BranchManagerController@dateWiseBranchIncome')->name('admin.branch.income.date');
        Route::get('staff/branch/income/{branch}/{staff}', 'BranchManagerController@staffWiseBranchIncome')->name('admin.branch.income.staff');

        //frontend setting route list
        Route::get('frontend/testimonial', 'FrontendSettingController@testimonial')->name('frontend.testimonial');
        Route::put('frontend/testimonial', 'FrontendSettingController@testimonialUpdate');
        Route::post('frontend/testimonial/store', 'FrontendSettingController@storeNewTestimonial')->name('frontend.storeTestimonial');
        Route::put('frontend/testimonial/{testimonial}', 'FrontendSettingController@updateNewTestimonial')->name('frontend.updateTestimonial');
        Route::delete('frontend/testimonial/{testimonial}/delete', 'FrontendSettingController@deleteTestimonial')->name('frontend.deleteTestimonial');
        Route::get('frontend/logoicon', 'FrontendSettingController@logoicon')->name('frontend.logoicon');
        Route::put('frontend/logoicon', 'FrontendSettingController@logoiconUpdate');
        Route::get('frontend/social', 'FrontendSettingController@social')->name('frontend.social');
        Route::post('frontend/social', 'FrontendSettingController@socialAdd');
        Route::put('frontend/social/{social}', 'FrontendSettingController@socialUpdate')->name('frontend.socialUpdate');
        Route::delete('frontend/social/{social}', 'FrontendSettingController@socialDestroy')->name('frontend.socialDestroy');
        Route::get('frontend/background', 'FrontendSettingController@background')->name('frontend.background');
        Route::put('frontend/background', 'FrontendSettingController@backgroundUpdate');
        Route::get('frontend/headertext', 'FrontendSettingController@headertextsetting')->name('frontend.headertext');
        Route::put('frontend/headertext/{setting}', 'FrontendSettingController@headertextsettingUpdate')->name('frontend.headertextupdate');
        Route::get('frontend/curriercount', 'FrontendSettingController@curriercount')->name('frontend.curriercount');
        Route::put('frontend/curriercount/{setting}', 'FrontendSettingController@curriercountUpdate')->name('frontend.curriercountupdate');
        Route::get('frontend/aboutus', 'FrontendSettingController@aboutus')->name('frontend.aboutus');
        Route::PUT('frontend/aboutus', 'FrontendSettingController@updateAboutUs');
        Route::get('frontend/contactus', 'FrontendSettingController@contactus')->name('frontend.contactus');
        Route::PUT('frontend/contactus', 'FrontendSettingController@updateContactus');
        Route::get('frontend/footer', 'FrontendSettingController@footer')->name('frontend.footer');
        Route::PUT('frontend/footer', 'FrontendSettingController@updateFooter');
        Route::get('frontend/searchcurrier', 'FrontendSettingController@searchcurrier')->name('frontend.searchcurrier');
        Route::put('frontend/searchcurrier', 'FrontendSettingController@searchcurrierUpdate');
        //faq crud
        Route::get('frontend/faq', 'FrontendSettingController@faq')->name('frontend.faq');
        Route::post('frontend/faq/store', 'FrontendSettingController@storeNewFaq')->name('frontend.storeFaq');
        Route::put('frontend/faq/{faq}', 'FrontendSettingController@updateNewFaq')->name('frontend.updateFaq');
        Route::delete('frontend/faq/{faq}/delete', 'FrontendSettingController@deleteFaq')->name('frontend.deleteFaq');

        //service section route list
        Route::get('frontend/services', 'FrontendSettingController@services')->name('frontend.services');
        Route::put('frontend/services', 'FrontendSettingController@servicesUpdate');
        Route::post('frontend/services/store', 'FrontendSettingController@storeNewServices')->name('frontend.storeServices');
        Route::put('frontend/services/{services}', 'FrontendSettingController@updateNewServices')->name('frontend.updateServices');
        Route::delete('frontend/services/{services}/delete', 'FrontendSettingController@deleteServices')->name('frontend.deleteServices');

        //visitor message list show
        Route::get('front/visitorMessage', 'FrontendSettingController@showVisitorMessage')->name('frontend.visitorMessage');
        Route::delete('front/visitorMessage/{message}', 'FrontendSettingController@deleteVisitorMessage')->name('frontend.deleteVisitorMessage');
    });
});




Auth::routes();

// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('manager', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm'
]);
Route::post('manager', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'
]);



Route::group(['namespace' => 'Manager'], function () {Route::post('password/reset', 'PasswordResetController@sendResetLink')->name('password.reset');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'PasswordResetController@resetLink')->name('password.token');
    Route::put('password/change', 'PasswordResetController@passwordReset')->name('password.change');        
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'manager', 'prefix' => 'manager', 'namespace' => 'Manager'], function () {

    //user profile & credentials routes
    Route::get('profile', 'ManagerController@profileView')->name('manager.profile');
    Route::put('profile', 'ManagerController@updateProfile');

    //all branch list route
    Route::get('branch/list', 'ManagerController@branchList')->name('manager.branchlist');

    //all branch staff route list
    Route::resource('branchstaff', 'BranchStaffController');
    Route::post('branchstaff/changepassword', 'BranchStaffController@changePassword')->name('branchstaff.changepassword');

    //Departure & Upcoming courier info route list
    Route::get('departure/currier', 'CurrierInfoController@departureBranchCurrierList')->name('departure.manager');
    Route::get('upcoming/currier', 'CurrierInfoController@upcomingBranchCurrierList')->name('upcoming.manager');
    Route::get('departure/invoice/{currierInfo}', 'CurrierInfoController@currierInvoice')->name('manager.departure.invoice');
    Route::get('upcoming/invoice/{currierInfo}', 'CurrierInfoController@upcomingCurrierInvoice')->name('manager.upcoming.invoice');

    //print slip route list
    Route::get('currier/slip/{id}', 'CurrierInfoController@printSlipView')->name('manager.currier.slip');

    //branch income route 
    Route::get('branch/income', 'CompanyPaymentController@branchWiseIncome')->name('manager.branch.income');
    Route::get('branch/income/date/{date}', 'CompanyPaymentController@dateWiseBranchIncome')->name('manager.branch.income.date');
    Route::get('branch/income/staff/{staff}', 'CompanyPaymentController@staffWiseBranchIncome')->name('manager.branch.income.staff');

    //change password route
    Route::get('changePassword', 'ManagerController@changePassword')->name('manager.changepassword');
    Route::put('changePassword', 'ManagerController@updatePassword');
});


Route::group(['prefix' => 'staff', 'namespace' => 'Staff'], function () {


        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('staff/login');
        })->name('staff');
        Route::post('authenticate', 'LoginController@authenticate')->name('staff.authenticate');
        
        
        Route::get('password/request', 'PasswordResetController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('staff.password.request');
        Route::post('password/reset', 'PasswordResetController@sendResetLink')->name('staff.password.reset');
        Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'PasswordResetController@resetLink')->name('staff.password.token');
        Route::put('password/change', 'PasswordResetController@passwordReset')->name('staff.password.change');
        
        
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'staff',], function () {

        Route::post('logout', function () {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('staff');
        })->name('staff.logout');
        //staff dashboard
        Route::get('dashboard', 'StaffController@dashboard')->name('staff.dashboard');

        //user profile & credentials routes
        Route::get('profile', 'StaffController@profileView')->name('staff.profile');
        Route::put('profile', 'StaffController@updateProfile');

        //branch list
        Route::get('branch/list', 'StaffController@branchList')->name('staff.branchlist');

        //courier info route list
        Route::resource('currier', 'CurrierInfoController');
        Route::get('currier/invoice/{currierInfo}', 'CurrierInfoController@currierInvoice')->name('currier.invoice');
        Route::put('currier/receive/staff', 'CurrierInfoController@receiveCurrier')->name('currier.receive');
        Route::put('currier/payment/staff', 'CurrierInfoController@paidCurrier')->name('currier.payment.staff');
        //print slip route list
        Route::get('currier/slip/{id}', 'CurrierInfoController@printSlipView')->name('staff.currier.slip');

        //search deliver currier
        Route::get('currier/deliver/search', 'CurrierInfoController@searchDeliverCurrier')->name('currier.deliver.search');
        Route::post('currier/deliver/search', 'CurrierInfoController@showDeliverCurrier');
        //send deliver notification
        Route::get('currier/deliver/notification', 'CurrierInfoController@notifyView')->name('currier.deliver.notify');
        Route::post('currier/deliver/notification', 'CurrierInfoController@findCurrier');
        Route::post('currier/deliiver/notification/send', 'CurrierInfoController@sendNotification')->name('send.notification.currier');
        //Cash Collection Route
        Route::get('cash/collection', 'CurrierInfoController@staffCasheCollection')->name('staff.cashe.collection');

        //change password route
        Route::get('changePassword', 'StaffController@changePassword')->name('staff.changepassword');
        Route::put('changePassword', 'StaffController@updatePassword');
        
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code involved to render that search form? Additionally, show your attempts to modify the behaviour

Comment: Hi, this is not my code, I'm only trying to modify my client's website before I got stuck on this. If there's any particular file where I can check for this, kindly let me know. Thanks

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Understood

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a name for `track` route and redirect to that route from `FrontController`.

```
Route::get('/track', function () {
    return view('track');
})->name('track.index');
```

Then from your `FrontController` try to redirect to that url from `searchCurrier` function.

```
public function searchCurrier(Request $request)
{
    // .......
    return redirect('track.index')->with([
        'key' => 'value'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It finally worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using a prefix for `track` and group the frontend routes instead.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    // This is your track url
    Route::get('/', function () {
        Route::view('track');
    });

    // Add all the other routes that are prefixed with track here
    Route::get('frontend/testimonial', 'FrontendSettingController@testimonial')->name('frontend.testimonial');
});
```

It would help if you post more code to see what is calling these routes too, but this should make the routes cleaner and I don't think you can return the track view the way you are doing it currently.

Comment: That was quick! Sorry, I was hoping on getting a response after some hours.

Comment: I'm trying to paste the code, but it seems too long. Let me create a new question with the complete code. Please, I'll be waiting for an answer from you.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my main question now. Please, check it out